# Асинхронное чтение/запись в Realm используя RXJava 2

Tags: java, android, rxjava, realm, rxandroid

Моя первая реализация асинхронной работы с помощью `RXJava 2`.

**Цель:**

Получить `json` данные с сервера библиотекой `Retrofit2`. Если успешно, то записать в `Realm` и сразу после записи получить обратно данные и отправить адаптеру `RecyclerView`.

Так вот, я все это реализовал таким образом:

```
private void fetchChatsFromNetwork(int count, AccessDataModel accessDataModel) {

    String accessToken = accessDataModel.getAccessToken();

    MyApplication.getRestApi().getChats(count, accessToken, Constants.api_version)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<ChatsModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(ChatsModel chatsModel) {
                    if (chatsRepository.hasData()) {

                        chatsRepository.updateChatsData(chatsModel)
                                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<ChatsModel>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(ChatsModel localChatsModel) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onSuccess updated!");
                                        iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(localChatsModel);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onError when update!");
                                        iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsError(e.getMessage());
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {
                                        dispose();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onComplete!");
                                    }
                                });

                    } else {
                        chatsRepository.insertChatsData(chatsModel)
                                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<ChatsModel>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(ChatsModel localChatsModel) {
                                        iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(localChatsModel);
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onSuccess inserted!");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                        iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsError(e.getMessage());
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onError when inserting!");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {
                                        dispose();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onComplete!");
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError" + t.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");
                }
            });
}
```

Я записываю данные в `Realm` в методе `onNext()` подписчика `MyApplication.getRestApi().getChats()`.

Вот код записи:

```
public Observable<ChatsModel> updateChatsData(final ChatsModel chatsModel) {

    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<ChatsModel>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<ChatsModel> e) throws Exception {
            if (chatsModel != null) {
                realm.executeTransactionAsync(
                        realm -> realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chatsModel),
                        () -> {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data success updated!");
                            ChatsModel localChatsModel = getAllChatsData();
                            e.onNext(localChatsModel);
                            e.onComplete();
                        },
                        error -> {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Update data failed!");
                            e.onError(error);
                        });
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Метод `updateChatsData()` записывает асинхронно и объявлен в другом классе.

Как видите мой метод `fetchChatsFromNetwork()` написан громоздко или мне так кажется.

**Вопрос:**

Правильно ли я делаю или нет, если нет, то как было бы правильнее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно полностью отвязать запись в БД от уведомления адаптера о новых данных.

1. Подпишитесь на `Observable`, выдающий выборку из БД и уведомляющий о ней адаптер.
2. При сетевом запросе полученные данные пишите в БД.

При таком способе `Observable` из первого пункта уведомит адаптер сразу после записи/обновлении данных в БД.

Саму запись в БД макже можно проще сделать через `flatMap` как-то так:

```
MyApplication.getRestApi().getChats(count, accessToken, Constants.api_version)
        .flatMap(data -> (chatsRepository.hasData() ? chatsRepository.updateChatsData(data) : chatsRepository.insertChatsData(data)).flatMap(data -> Observable.just(true)))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(
            aBoolean -> System.out.println("data in DB updated"),
            error -> System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage())
        );
```

Тут, возможно, придётся поиграться с заменой транзакций записей в БД с синхронных на асинхронные (скорее наоборот) из-за того, как работают асинхронные в потоках без `Looper`.

Comment: Извините, но я не совсем понял. Как `Observable` из первого пункта уведомит адаптер, если я отвязал его от уведомления адаптера?

Comment: @DevOma, я имею в виду, что у вас должно быть, грубо, 2 метода. 1-ый должен подписываться на изменение выборки в БД, а второй делать запрос в сеть и писать в БД. После записи в БД `Observable` в 1 методе сообщит о изменениях в БД и уведомит об этом адаптер.

Comment: Можно поподробнее, а то я уже 2 дня мучаюсь, как подписаться на изменение выборку в БД?

Comment: @DevOma, как-то так: `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Datamodel.class).findAllAsync().asObservable().filter(RealmList:isLoaded).subscribe(data->adapter.setData(data));`

Comment: Я так пробовал, только вот после `asObservable()` не никаких методов кроме cast, field, par, var

Comment: @DevOma 0_o странно... Какая версия `Realm`? Возможно надо `asFlowable()` использовать.

Comment: Версия: 3.7.2. нет к сожалению asFlowable, где то читал что есть метод asObservable2 но и его не оказалось

Comment: @DevOma, ага... Вроде версия реалма эта не поддерживает 2 версию rx. Надо или Rx понизить или реалм до 4 версии повысить и использовать `asFlowable()`

Comment: Спасибо, я не знал об этой версии. Попробую отпишусь..